# How to inject HttpClient in Angular library peer dependency?

Tags: angular

I'm facing `NullInjectorError` at a second level dependency and don't know how to properly provide it.

`LibA` is generated with Open-API typescript-angular and, as so, requires `HttpClient` to be injected.

`LibB` is an angular library I wrote which depends on `LibA` (and `angular-auth-oidc-client`)

As explained in this thread, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575, I verified `HttpClientModule` is imported in `AppModule` only and tried to provide `HttpClient` with DI, but I obviously do it incorectly.

Here is what I did:
`AppModule` imports [`HttpClientModule`, `LibAModule`, `LibBModule`] and provides [`HttpClient`], but I keep having `NullInjectorError` for `HttpClient`.

What did I miss?

Comment: Please give a proper [mre].

Comment: what ever u do
don't put  HttpClient in providers

Comment: check httpClinetModule and httpClinet both are importing  from '@angular/common/http';